# Do we alter the input string when converting a multi-tape Turing Machine to a single-tape Turing Machine?

Tags: turing-machines

I'm having difficulty understanding the conversion from a multi-tape Turing Machine $M$ to a single-tape Turing Machine $S$. Suppose that $M$ has 3 tapes with input strings $w_1 = 0110$, $w_2 = aaba$, and $w_3 = XXXX$, and configurations

$\textbf{0}110$

$aa\textbf{b}a$

$X\textbf{X}XX$,

where the bold-faced symbols represent the current positions of the read/write heads. The single-tape Turing Machine will have an input string of

$w = \#\textbf{0}110\#aa\textbf{b}a\#X\textbf{X}XX\#$

I'm unclear as to whether we have to delineate $w_1, w_2,$ and $w_3$ manually (i.e. the input string $w = 0110aabaXXXX$) , or if we alter the input string $w$ to include those hash delimiters (i.e. $w=\#0110\#aaba\#XXXX\#$).

Comment: Have you checked the definition of "a conversion from a multi-tape Turing Machine to a single-tape Turing Machine"? What does it say?

Comment: There is no mention in any of the three textbooks that I own. Nor is there in any of the online resources that I've consulted. I would not have asked here had I already known or had access to the answer to the question.